# jQuery panel to slide down then up on page load

Tags: jquery, delay, slidedown, slideup

This is suppose to be very simple, however I just can't get it to work as it should.

The following code should be able to do the following. As soon as page completes loading, a div (div#panel) at the top of the page should scroll down into view. After a few seconds delay the div should scroll back up out off view. The div should also be able to toggle/slide up and down as user clicks on a trigger.

Thanks in advance for advice/suggestions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
    setTimeout(function(){ 
    $("div#panel").slideUp("slow"); 
    }, 5000);

});

$(document).ready(function() {

    // Expand Panel
    $("#open").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
    }); 

    // Collapse Panel
    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideUp("slow"); 
    });         
});
```

Comment: code is correct what is not working here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to `hide()` the panel first, so it can slide into view.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#panel").hide();

    var autoTimer = null;

    autoTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
        autoTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            $("div#panel").slideUp("slow");
        }, 5000);
    },2000);

    $("#open").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
        if(autoTimer) clearTimeout(autoTimer);
        autoTimer = null;
    });

    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideUp("slow");
        if(autoTimer) clearTimeout(autoTimer);
        autoTimer = null;
    });         
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X9Vn4/6/

Comment: Brilliant! That seems to be the way to go. However, the div is sliding down prior to the page completes loading. Will play around a bit an see what can be done......

Comment: In that case, you can put the auto-sliding bits into the load function: `$(document).load(function(){...});`. That will only fire after your whole page has finished loading, including images.

Comment: DarthJDG - that make sense, however as this is a WordPress site it's unfortunately a bit more tricky. Is there maybe a way to use .delay()? I tried it but to no avail...

Comment: I don't see why binding into the load event would not work on a wordpress site, but if you just want to do a flat delay, you can wrap the auto-sliding code to another timeout like this: http://jsfiddle.net/X9Vn4/3/

Comment: `delay()` is more elegant for pure animations, but there might be reasons you want to cancel the timeout, such as if the user starts playing with the open/close buttons, you might not want to auto-open/close. Due to a bug in jQuery, there are problems with stopping delayed animations, so `clearTimeout()` should be the way to go. I edited my post, now it cancels auto-sliding if the user manually opened/closed the panel.

Comment: It looks good. Now however IE7 displays the div directly while loading and remove after loading. And then continue on to the delay, slideDown, slideUp.

Comment: Good stuff, will implement. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try this. Load slideUp when slideDown completes execution.

```
$('#id').slideDown(500, function(){
   setTimeout(function(){$('#id').fadeOut(500)}, 1500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this :
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout('slide_div()',5000);
  $('#open').click(function(){
      $('#pane1').slideDown('slow');
  });

  $('#close').click(function(){
      $('#pane1').slideUp('slow');
  });
});

function slide_div()
{
   $('#pane1').slideToggle();
 }
```